# Creating tiled rasters with colors for Leaflet without R?

Tags: raster, gdal, leaflet

I have a .tif files with only NAs and 1s. Then, I use `gdaldem color-relief` to give the tif colors. Then I use `gdal2tile.py` on these tif files for tiling maps. But the tiled maps don't show any colors, only black and white.

In R I can add colors for rasters with leaflet. But I am not using R, what can I do to create color rasters for leaflet?

----- Edit ------
The `color.txt` file looks like this:

```
0, 255 255 255 255
0, 0 0 0 0
```

Then I did `gdaldem color-relief -of GTiff test.tif colot.txt output.tif`. The output.tif does have colors. Then, I use `gdal2tiles.py -z 1-6 output.tif tile_folder` And from the output tile maps, there is no colors.

Comment: Can you show the full commands you are using? Including the color table information for `gdaldem color-relief`.

Comment: Yeah, and I have updated my post. Thank you for the reply!